# multiple button clicks, click correct btn show img, click wrong buttons show X

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

would you please help with the below code please :). Thank you in Advance.

I want to be able to click on the correct button e.g. H and show the check mark and a link forward (image), if the user clicks on the wrong button the X image is shown until the correct button is clicked all button are disabled and only the forward button is clicked. Any help is appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!--When the correct button is clicked, the checkmark image and the next image bellow should appear on table-->
<button id="d" name="d" type="button" onclick="toggleBtn('correct')">D</button>

<!--When the Wrong buttons are clicked the X mark appeas until user clicks the corect answer-->
<button id="h"  name="h" type="button" onclick="toggleBtn('wrong')">H</button><br/><br/>
<button id="a" name="a" type="button" onclick="toggleBtn('wrong')">A</button>
<button id="x" name="x" type="button" onclick="toggleBtn('wrong')">X</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleBtn(id) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if (e.style.display == 'block')
                e.style.display = 'block';
       else
    e.style.display = 'block';
                
        }            
</script>

<table>

<tr>
<td>

<!--This element should be shown with the check mark when the correct button is clicked-->
<img style="display:none;" id="correct" src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/17/01/07/e9de203a108e1511282a8d35e8857090.jpg" width="100" height="132">

<!--This element should be shown when the wrong button is clicked-->    
<img style="display:none;" id="wrong" src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/12/20/74ab28b776c19ad9411de1a5c2c98807.jpg" width="100" height="132">
</td>

<!--This element should be shown with the check mark when the correct button is clicked, all buttons should be disabled except the next-->
<td><img style="display:none;" id="correct" title="forward"src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/17/03/21/1b78f0da4326aa5f574061d9b403340e.jpg" width="100" height="132"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your code you have multiple elements with same `id` :(

Comment: At the beginning of your `toggleBtn` Function. Add that it hides both images first. Then reveal the clicked images as you are doing right now. For example: `document.getElementById('wrong').style.display = 'none';` and also: `document.getElementById('correct').style.display = 'none';`

Comment: I don't see why it's tagged with AngularJS when it's not used.

Comment: Thank you Aleksey, it shouldn't be tagged with Angular, typo.

Comment: Thank you Aleksey, if you have a Angular solution that would be good too :). Your code works well showing both wrong and correct button image when clicked. I'm looking for a way where user clicks on a button once, e.g. if the correct button is clicked, the check image and the forward image is shown and only the forward image is clickable, if the wrong image is clicked the x is show until the correct answer is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below is a solution using a function to hide both the `correct` and `wrong` image when the user clicks any button.

On a side note, there a couple issues with your code :

- There are two `IMG` elements with the `correct` id. id's are supposed to be unique.
- The if / else structure in your toggleBtn function seems useless. The same instruction appears in your if and your else block.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!--When the correct button is clicked, the checkmark image and the next image bellow should appear on table-->
<button id="d" name="d" type="button" onclick="toggleBtn('correct')">D</button>

<!--When the Wrong buttons are clicked the X mark appeas until user clicks the corect answer-->
<button id="h"  name="h" type="button" onclick="toggleBtn('wrong')">H</button><br/><br/>
<button id="a" name="a" type="button" onclick="toggleBtn('wrong')">A</button>
<button id="x" name="x" type="button" onclick="toggleBtn('wrong')">X</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleBtn(id) {
 // hiding the previous result
 hideResults();
 var e = document.getElementById(id);
 e.style.display = 'block';
  
  if (id === "correct") {
    document.getElementById("forward").style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function hideResults() {
 document.getElementById("correct").style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById("wrong").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("forward").style.display = 'none';

}
</script>

<table>

<tr>
<td>

<!--This element should be shown with the check mark when the correct button is clicked-->
<img style="display:none;" id="correct" src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/17/01/07/e9de203a108e1511282a8d35e8857090.jpg" width="100" height="132">

<!--This element should be shown when the wrong button is clicked-->    
<img style="display:none;" id="wrong" src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/12/20/74ab28b776c19ad9411de1a5c2c98807.jpg" width="100" height="132">
</td>

<!--This element should be shown with the check mark when the correct button is clicked, all buttons should be disabled except the next-->

<td><img style="display:none;" id="forward" title="forward"src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/17/03/21/1b78f0da4326aa5f574061d9b403340e.jpg" width="100" height="132"></td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you RogerC, you are right, there should be unique IDs, but how can enable the other image when the correct image is click? I want to be able to go to the next buttons when the correct answer is clicked. so the Tick and the forward images should be shown.

Comment: @adasilva I edited so the forward button shows up when the correct answer is clicked.

Comment: Thank you very Much RogerC, got some results but my coding is way longer than yours :) will use your code. Very much appreciate you taking your time in helping :)